# Converting timestamp to YYYY/MM/DD in POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

How can I convert a column holding timestamp date to 'YYYY/MM/DD' format in POSTGRES.
Eg. column A has value like -- 2021-08-24 13:23:21
and I want to convert it to '2021-08-24'

Comment: Do you want to strip the time from the field and store it that way in the database, or do you just want to display the date only?

Comment: What data type exactly is that column?

Comment: Use `to_char` as documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is useful for you to understand Date Conversion.

```
SELECT Cast(Now() as Date) as YourDate;

SELECT Now()::date as YourDate;

Select To_Char(Now(),'yyyy/mm/dd') as YourDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `::date` to cast it to date

```
SELECT mycolumn::date FROM mytable;
```

Comment: That assumes the [DateStyle](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) is set appropriately.